# How do I stop cell phone interference on my wired speakers?

Tags: audio, speakers, interference

I read [Why do cell phones disturb my speaker?](https://superuser.com/questions/183137/why-do-cell-phones-disturb-my-speaker), and while it does explain what's going on, it doesn't give any solutions.

I'm using Creative A60 speakers (I think I bought these back in 2011, but not sure), plugged in through 3.5mm audio jack in the back of my computer. They're beeping/buzzing regularly when my phone is on my computer desk. I don't have any room to move my phone away from my speakers in a way that doesn't increase the risk of accidentally pushing it off, so I'm looking for an alternative option to make this interference go away. It's extremely annoying, especially when it happens at 11 PM when everyone else is asleep, and I want to get rid of it, preferably without buying new speakers.

How do I stop this interference?

Comment: Have you seen [What is the cause of interference noises in my PC speakers and how can I get rid of them?](https://superuser.com/questions/432401/what-is-the-cause-of-interference-noises-in-my-pc-speakers-and-how-can-i-get-rid)

Comment: @AndrewMorton I haven't, because it didn't appear in the suggested questions and neither google nor SE search found it for me.

Comment: I googled for "pc speakers stop cell phone interference" (sans quotes).

Comment: @AndrewMorton I searched "stop cell phone interference sound" and most of the solutions were for cell phones themselves. I didn't consider adding "pc speakers" in the search.